# Tense used to put forward a proposal

Tags: temps-grammatical, questions, mode-grammatical, conditions

In the following proposals

> Et si on faisait un pique-nique?

I do not understand why an author uses imparfait, whereas in the sentence

> On pourrait aller dans la forêt

as you can see conditionnel présent is used.

Please explain

Comment: How different is it different from English? You would use *What if we went on a pique-nique?* or *We could go to the forest*, respectively using preterit and conditionnal.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon Could you please enlighten, how to make out whether there is a condition involved or not? (I tend to think of it as follows—if X happens then Y happens...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, the use of *imparfait* comes because of the *si*.
Let's continue the example:

> Si on faisait un pique-nique, on mangerait bien.

*Si* introduces a condition, and thus should always be followed by *imparfait*. And then, the next verb is *conditionnel*.

Comment: Si je trouve un contre-exemple, je l’ajouterai en commentaire.

Comment: Of course a condition is not necessarily in *imparfait*. If not about proposals, *present* is possible as well.