# How to identify a condition (for use of conditionnel présent)?

Tags: mode-grammatical, conditionnel, conditions, concordance-des-temps

This is a bit related to my other question and comment on the usage of *conditionnel présent*
([Tense used to put forward a proposal](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7329/tense-used-to-put-forward-a-proposal)).

Why is there no *conditionnel* in the following example:

> Si je suis libre, je viens.

*Si* introduces a condition, so shouldn't the following verb (*venir*) be in *conditionnel présent*?

Comment: Un « si » au présent est suivi d’un futur (ou d’un présent à valeur de futur, comme ici). Un « si » à l’imparfait est suivi d’un conditionnel. Si j’ai le temps, je répondrai à ton autre question ce soir.

Comment: Merçi. Si c'est vous convient, répondrez en Anglais s'il vous plait. Je peux juste comprende court et simples sentences maintenant.:-)

Comment: @AbhimanyuArora You French isn't bad ☺ but if I may correct you, I think you meant: "Merci. Si ça vous convient, répondez en anglais s'il vous plaît. Je peux juste comprendre des phrases courtes et simples pour le moment.". He said that "si" is only followed by a conditional if the sentence is in the past (à l'imparfait), when it isn't (like here) we either use a future or a present (but a present, which actually means a future). (Well, he said this more or less, I hope the translation is right)

Comment: @Édouard: au conditionnel je répondraiS

Comment: It’s a *futur simple*, hence *“je répondrai”*. And I didn’t have enough time, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, the conditional would be used if the condition was a **false hypothetical**. It isn't used in a hypothetical whose truth is yet to be determined.

> Si j'étais libre, je viendrais. Mais j'ai un autre rendez-vous, donc je ne viendrai pas.
>   *If I was available, I'd come. But I have another meeting, so I won't come.*

(In this case, « j'étais libre » is the **false hypothetical** as described in the first sentence above. Why? The second sentence vindicates that you're at a meeting so you were not in fact free.)

> Si je suis libre, je viendrai. Je saurai demain si je suis libre ou non.
>   *If I'm available, I'll come. I'll know tomorrow whether I'm available.*

(Pay attention to *viendrai*: future indicative vs. *viendrais*: present conditional. There is no future conditional in French.)

In French, it is impossible to use the future or the conditional after *si*. Therefore, even if the condition applies to the future, we use the present in the condition clause. The same happens in English, by the way.

Such conditional sentences tend not to be in the present tense, because if the action is happening now, then you know whether the condition is true or not. So “*Si je suis libre, je viens*” [can sound a little strange out of context](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7335/how-to-identify-a-condition-for-use-of-conditionnel-present#comment12154_7342). However there are situations where it can happen and is idiomatic:

- If the action is habitual, rather than punctual.

  > L'association se réunit toutes les semaines. Si je suis libre, je viens.
  >   *The organization meets every week. If I'm avaiable, I come to the meeting.*

  It is also possible in this sentence to use *quand*, because the meaning ends up being the same: when a meeting is held and I'm available, I go. When *quand* is possible, we tend to use it in preference to *si* in such a situation. However there are cases where only *si* works.

  > L'association se réunit deux fois par semaine. Si je suis libre, je viens le jeudi.
  >   The organization meets twice a week. If I'm available, I go to the Thursday meetings.
- In casual French, it is common to use the present instead of the future.

  > Je viens demain.
  >   *I'm coming tomorrow.*
  >
  > Si je suis libre demain, je viens.
  >   *If I'm free tomorrow, I'll come.*
- The hypothetical might be unknown because it concerns an action that is happening in a remote location. This obviously can't happen in the first person.

  > S'il est au courant du problème, je suis sûr qu'il y travaille.
  >   *If he's aware of the problem, I'm sure he's working on it.*

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is very similar to English. We have **three conditional sentences**.

---

`if` + `simple present` for things that may happen.

> If I **see** Tim, I will **explain** him your mistake.

The same example in French:

> Si je **vois** Tim, je lui **expliquerai** ton erreur.

---

`if` + `preterit modal` for things that might happen.

> If I **won** a billion euros, I **would go** to space.

And in French:

> Si je **gagnais** un milliard d'euros, j'**irais** dans l'espace.

---

`if` + `past perfect modal` for things that may have happened but did not.

> If I **had been** a king, I **would have bought** a golden sword.

The same in French:

> Si **j'avais été** roi, **j'aurais acheté** une épée en or.

Comment: The example sentence uses (present, present) and not (present, future). You don't discuss this case.

Comment: Ok! Your example is not correct in French. It should be:
Si je suis libre, je viendrai.

Comment: [pas d'accord](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7335/how-to-identify-a-condition-for-use-of-conditionnel-present/7343#7343).

Comment: En fait, tout dépend si l'on veut marquer l'idée d'avenir ou pas. Les deux propositions sont bonnes. Le verbe venir sous-entend une action dans le temps mais la solution présent-présent fonctionne également pour une condition simple comme ici.